# What is this section of pipe on the back side of my drain?

Tags: plumbing

Looking at removing a garbage disposal and re-plumb without a disposal.  I forgot there was this extra section of vertical pipe at the back.  Looks to be some sort of vent?

See image, area labelled A

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks to me like an "air admittance valve" (AAV). Its function would be to allow air into (but not out of) the drainage system.

In any case, you could remove the disposal and connect a regular strainer basket in its place, leaving the AAV as it is.

Comment: I believe they are used where a normal (nowadays, anyway) DWV vent pipe to the roof is not available.